# How to move section entry from elf?

Tags: linux, format, elf

ELF format：

1. 0x00 ~ 0x33 is file header
2. section headers and segment headers must be consecutive

And section entry can store in any position, specify by offset

So I want to move a section entry(.dynsym) to another position, and, for ELF32 only

The utility download link: 
http://www10.zippyshare.com/v/25037401/file.html

```
The Process：
1. ModifyElf.exe
   I write a utility called ModifyElf.exe, it can move a section entry of elf file. Usage:
   ModifyElf.exe <srcfile> <dstfile> <sectionname> <mov2fileend:0|1> <clearold:0|1>
   args:
   <srcfile>         ->  src so file path
   <dstfile>         ->  dst so file path
   <sectionname>     ->  section name, just support ".dynsym " currently
   <mov2fileend:0|1> ->  mov2fileend:0 move section entry to the unused zero zone of so file, don't increase file size
                         mov2fileend:1 move section entry to the end of so file，will increase file size
   <clearold:0|1>    ->  clearold:0 don't clear the original section entry
                         clearold:1 set all bytes of original section entry to 0xFF

   for example：
   ModifyElf.exe e:\test\libfoo_ori.so e:\test\libfoo.so .dynsym mov2fileend:0 clearold:1

2. libfoo.so and linux_hello
   linux_hello call dlopen to load libfoo.so，and call myfn from libfoo.so, myfn just printf a string

   neil0@vm32:~/share/test$ sudo chmod a+x linux_hello 
   neil0@vm32:~/share/test$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/share/test:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   neil0@vm32:~/share/test$ ./linux_hello 
   dlopen ok!
   call myfn...!

3. modify and exec
   run ModifyElf.exe e:\test\libfoo_ori.so e:\test\libfoo.so .dynsym mov2fileend:0 clearold:1
   move section entry to zero zone, get a new so file, replace it in linux，and exec linux_hello, it's OK！You can use file compare tool to see diff between libfoo.so and libfoo_ori.so

   run ModifyElf.exe e:\test\libfoo_ori.so e:\test\libfoo.so .dynsym mov2fileend:1 clearold:1
   move section entry to file end，get a new so file, replace it in linux，and exec linux_hello, it's said "Segmentation fault"
```

So could you tell me why I can't move it to file end and how should I do if I want to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?  What does "move to another position" mean?  Typical ELF files are relocatable, so you can't (normally) control their position in the address space.  Maybe you want to move it to another location in the file?  I don't understand why you pasted the documentation for the tool here, that's not helpful.  Please explain your problem, not what you think the solution is.

Comment: The tool's purpose is: move data automatically. Yes, I want to move section entry to another location in the file, and I do it successfully by move data to the zero zone of file, it' ok. However, when I use the same way to move it to the file end, it's show "Segmentation fault", I want to solve it.

Comment: That's still not explaining what your **problem** is.  Why do you want to relink an ELF file?  Why the .dynsym section? What is a "zero zone of file"?

Comment: My final purpose is to add a lib to a binary .so file. So, need to change some section entry data(add lib string and so on...) and related offset. However, there is no padding spaces after original section data, so I must move it to another location. There are two choices: move to padding space(zero zone), or move to file end(increase file size). I successfully do it(just move, no change) with the first way, but failed in second way. The operations seem to all the same except the different location. I want to know how to do it by the second way, thanks

Comment: I feared it was something like this.  Symbol offsets aren't your only problem.  You're trying to relink a library, which is a Deep Voodoo problem.  Among other things, a correct solution will be architecture-dependent.  Just don't.

Comment: Maybe it's very difficult, but I really want to try it. Could anyone download my util and test it?